# Expression Engine multi-product order form

Tags: php, forms, expressionengine, tabular

Allow the following image:

[image]

Basically I have a table with a list of products I have stored in expression engine.  I need people to be able to fill in the quantites of each product that they need and submit the order.

There is no money being exchanged here.  I need the order to be sent via email - thats all.  Most importantly I only what the email to display the orders that have positive quantity values and a total price for the order. The quantity sub-total will be based on "Distributor (£) column".

Question: How can I collect the information from the table and put it into a "cart" of sorts so it can be email to me

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I have asked the question

Comment: Suppose it is a PHP questions: Where is the PHP code that cause the problem? And what problem does it cause? BTW: it is a good idea to mark a question with a question mark.